# Django unit test, how to run migrations on its respective multi-database?

Tags: django

For example, I have 2 apps, App A has models in `default` DB , and App B has models in `other_db`.

eg.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {....},
    'other_db': {....}
}
```

When I run test, it always try to run migration again on database A and causes error about stuff already exists.

Is it possible to tell Django only run App A's migration on `default` test db, and App B's migration on `other_db` test db?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `using()` clause to specify which db should be used to perform operations

```
Model.objects.using('database_b').all()
```

which run this query on `database_b` instead default db.

You can read more about using from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database)

Comment: I already have databaserouter for this, I am only having issue on unit tests when test database are being setup.

Comment: Try saving in the same database, refer to this., [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save)